# solution to post-back gridview by asynchronous without blink on asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

need to post back pop window gridview without postback?

dopostback method create blink on asp.net page but here i need without blink and with post-back action

```
function sample()
{
 __doPostBack('GridView2.ClientID', '');
}
```

Comment: Would you please elaborate your question? Scenario and problem you're facing.

Comment: i h'v one text-box and button, when i click btn it ll call popup window, if i give any-keyword on text-box, i need to filter grid-view inside the popup wndw, bt this functiona work fine with flicking on full page, i need post back without flicking on page

Comment: if i use this function __doPostBack('GridView2.ClientID', ''); refresh work on grid-view, bt which is create flickering this is problem

Comment: need post-back the grid-view without flickering on page

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the "flickering" you are seeing is the page doing a full post back. If you want to avoid "flickering" when doing a post back then you need to do a partial-page update. Take a look at [asp update panels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) on how to achieve this.